# Loading specific products

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce

I have lots of products and I want to filter them a certain way.
I want to retrieve all products that have stock = 1 or where product.myField = checked.

I don't know how to do this exactly. This is what I have for now

```
{% for prod in craft.commerce.products({
    search: 'myField:0 or hasVariant:{hasStock:true}'   
}).type(myType).order(sort ~ ' ' ~ order).limit(35) %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried Commerce myself but I think something like this should work:

```
{% set products = craft.commerce.products.type(yourType) %}

//make an empty array
{% set filteredProducts = [] %}

{% for entry in products %}
    //check for your conditions
    {% if (entry.checkboxFieldhandle) or (entry.hasStock) %}
        //add each entry to your products array
        {% set filteredProducts = filteredProducts|merge([entry]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: merge works on arrays: `filteredProducts|merge([entry])` might work.

Comment: @MarionNewlevant you're right, edited

Comment: awesome thanks!